# Ascending and Descending on Powershell query

Tags: powershell

Below query will list down the cmdlets in power shell.

```
get-command -CommandType cmdlet | Group-Object -Property verb
```

In that i need to sort the column count in descending order and then name column in ascending order. Below queries are not giving expected results.

```
get-command -CommandType cmdlet | Group-Object -Property verb | Sort-Object Count, name -Descending
get-command -CommandType cmdlet | Group-Object -Property verb | Sort-Object Count -Descending | Sort-Object name
get-command -CommandType cmdlet | Group-Object -Property verb | Sort-Object Count -Descending,  name
```

Please help me in this with single query in PS

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following your logic here. How can you passably sort anything by 2 different properties simultaneously?

Comment: @Mosheperez Easily? First you sort by the first property, then for each item with equal sort order based on the first one, you sort by the second property etc.

Answer (score 6):

You can override the order for an individual property by supplying a hashtable with a `Descending` item:

```
Get-Command -CommandType cmdlet |Group-Object Verb |Sort-Object Count,@{Expression='Name';Descending=$false} -Descending
```