# How to filter some information from physicaldisk using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I want to filter some information from physical disk. Then, write it to a file as an output file.

This is my phsicaldisk looks like:

When I try this

```
$GetPhysicalDisk = Get-PhysicalDisk |
                   Select-Object DeviceID, FriendlyName, MediaType, BusType, Size |
                   Format-Table
```

```
DeviceID FriendlyName             MediaType   BusType          Size
-------- ------------             ---------   -------          ----
4        SanDisk Ultra USB 3.0    Unspecified USB       61505273856
2        TOSHIBA DT01ACA100       HDD         RAID    1000204886016
0        INTEL SSDSC2BF180A4H SED SSD         RAID     180045766656
1        INTEL SSDSC2BF180A4H     SSD         RAID     180045766656
6        INTEL OPTANE             SSD         NVMe      15733161984
5        SAMSUNG                  SSD         NVMe     512060514304
```

I want to filter those information. I want to exclude disk with `BusType="USB", MediaType="Unspecified", "Bustype=NVMe with size less than 64GB".`
After I filter it, I have to arrange it from the first priority, like this

```
1st Priority = "BusType=NVMe and MediaType=SSD"
2nd Priority = "BusType=RAID and MediaType=SSD"  
3rd Priority = "BusType=RAID and MediaType=HDD"
```

I tried this

```
$GetSSDHDD = Get-PhysicalDisk |
             Select-Object DeviceID, FriendlyName, MediaType, BusType, Size |
             Where-Object -FilterScript {$_.MediaType -eq "Unspecified"} {$_.BusType -eq "USB"} {$_.MediaType -eq "NVMe" -and $_.Size -lt 61505273856 }          
$Report = $GetSSDHDD | Out-File .\Output -Force
```

My expectation result of output file is like this

```
DeviceID FriendlyName             MediaType   BusType          Size Priority
-------- ------------             ---------   -------          ---- -------- 
2        TOSHIBA DT01ACA100       HDD         RAID    1000204886016        4    
0        INTEL SSDSC2BF180A4H SED SSD         RAID     180045766656        3
1        INTEL SSDSC2BF180A4H     SSD         RAID     180045766656        2
5        SAMSUNG                  SSD         NVMe     512060514304        1
```

```
###Updated
$prio = @{
    'NVMe/SSD' = 1
    'SATA/SSD' = 2
    'SATA/HDD' = 3
    'RAID/SSD' = 4
    'RAID/HDD' = 5

}
Get-PhysicalDisk |
    Select-Object DeviceID, FriendlyName, MediaType, BusType, Size | 
    Group-Object { '{0}/{1}' -f $_.BusType, $_.MediaType}, {$_.BusType -eq "RAID", $_.Size -lt 181045766656} |
    Where-Object { $prio.Contains($_.Name) } |
    Sort-Object { $prio[$_.Name] } |
    Select-Object -Expand Group | 
    Export-Csv 'Report.csv' -NoType
```

Comment: So you want priority ranking first by whether it's `NVMe` over `Raid` then `SSD` over `HDD`?

Comment: Yes, That's right. And exculde the `Unspecified USB`

Comment: Read _Use multiple conditions_ in [`Where-Object` Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/Where-Object).

Answer (score 3):

Build a hashtable with your priorities (so you can use a numeric sort order):

```
$prio = @{
    'SSD/NVMe' = 1
    'SSD/RAID' = 2
    'HDD/RAID' = 3
}
```

Then group your results by the combination of media type and bus type, filter out groups that don't appear in the priorities. Finally sort by priority and expand the groups.

```
Get-PhysicalDisk |
    Select-Object DeviceID, FriendlyName, MediaType, BusType, Size |
    Group-Object { '{0}/{1}' -f $_.MediaType, $_.BusType } |
    Where-Object { $prio.Contains($_.Name) } |
    Sort-Object { $prio[$_.Name] } |
    Select-Object -Expand Group |
    Export-Csv 'output.csv' -NoType
```

Comment: Thank you @Ansgar, but I also need to consider the size, if I have the same MediaType and BusType, the first priority is the the smallest size. Thanks

Comment: @SBR You can sort each group individually by replacing the `Select-Object` that expands the group with a `ForEach-Object`. Consider that your homework.

Comment: Could you please help me how to do it? I m still confused :(

Comment: Confused about what? Using a `ForEach-Object` in a pipeline is about one of the most basic things in PowerShell. If you don't know how to use that you need to find a PowerShell tutorial before continuing any further.

Comment: Hi @Ansgar, I updated it my code to exclude size, could you please help me to check it, I can not get the result. Thanks

Comment: @SBR That needs to be a `Where-Object` filter before the `Group-Object`, and you need to connect the clauses with an `-and`, not a comma. For further troubleshooting: run only the first step of the pipeline and see what output you get, then run first and second and check the output, then the first three, and so on.

Comment: I got the solution to filter if the "Bustype=NVMe with size less than 64GB".
My other problem is, I have to sort it if I have the same "Bustype", I have to sort it from small size, help me please @Ansgar

Comment: @SBR I already told you what you need to do for that in my first comment (see above).

Comment: Could you please give me an example?

Answer (score 0):

- If I put together all the information from Q & A & comments,
- simulate your disks
- 1st apply your restrictions with a 'Where-Object'
- insert the Priority with a `calculated property`

```
## Q:\Test\2019\08\14\SO_57491415.ps1
# simulate Get-PhysicalDisk
$GetPhysicalDisk = @"
DeviceID,FriendlyName,MediaType,BusType,Size
4,SanDisk Ultra USB 3.0,Unspecified,USB,61505273856
2,TOSHIBA DT01ACA100,HDD,RAID,1000204886016
0,INTEL SSDSC2BF180A4H SED,SSD,RAID,180045766656
1,INTEL SSDSC2BF180A4H,SSD,RAID,180045766656
5,SAMSUNG,SSD,NVMe,512060514304
6,INTEL OPTANE,SSD,NVMe,15733161984
"@ -split '\r?\n' | ConvertFrom-Csv

$prio = @{
    'NVMe/SSD' = 1
    'SATA/SSD' = 2
    'SATA/HDD' = 3
    'RAID/SSD' = 4
    'RAID/HDD' = 5
}


$GetPhysicalDisk |
    Where-Object {($_.BusType -ne 'USB') -and
                  ($_.MediaType -ne 'Unspecified') -and
                !(($_.BusType -eq 'NVMe') -and
           ([int64]$_.Size) -lt 64GB) } |
    Select-Object DeviceID, FriendlyName, MediaType, BusType, Size,
                  @{n='Priority';e={$prio[('{0}/{1}' -f $_.BusType, $_.MediaType)]}}| 
    Format-Table -Auto
```

I get this output:

```
> Q:\Test\2019\08\14\SO_57491415.ps1

DeviceID FriendlyName             MediaType BusType Size          Priority
-------- ------------             --------- ------- ----          --------
2        TOSHIBA DT01ACA100       HDD       RAID    1000204886016        5
0        INTEL SSDSC2BF180A4H SED SSD       RAID    180045766656         4
1        INTEL SSDSC2BF180A4H     SSD       RAID    180045766656         4
5        SAMSUNG                  SSD       NVMe    512060514304         1
```

Comment: Hi @LotPings, Thank you so much. But I found one problem, once I have the same `BusType` and different Size, It does not sort the priority from the smaller size. Could you please help.

Comment: And I don want to make the same priority like priority `4` , that case it will pick randomly for the priority

Comment: You simply can't specify the Priority by two other properties and then beef about that decision. What you *can* do is sort different properties differently, some [ascending other descending](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50785208/ascending-and-descending-on-powershell-query)